# Unique results from joined queries with NHibernate LINQ provider

Tags: nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping, linq-to-nhibernate

I'm using NHibernate 2.1 with the LINQ provider and the results I get back from this query have multiple root nodes:

```
public IList<Country> GetAllCountries()
{
  List<Country> results = (from country in _session.Linq<Country>()
                           from states in country.StateProvinces
                           orderby country.DisplayOrder, states.Description 
                           select country)
                           .Distinct()
                           .ToList();

            return results;
}
```

I know that using the Criteria API you can call DistinctRootEntityResultTransformer() to ensure that you get a unique root node, but I'm in the process of switching most of my queries over to the NHibernate LINQ provider, and I don't see an equavalient.

http://nhforge.org/wikis/howtonh/get-unique-results-from-joined-queries.aspx

Comment: If you change your mapping from FetchType.Join to FetchType.Select, it will fix this problem (as far as getting the right results). But as far as the Disctin() call goes, I suspect the Distinct() in the Linq implementation is bugged.

Comment: I second Chris's assertion about the LINQ Distinct() method.  It doesn't work the way one expects.  Hopefully, this will be corrected in a later version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the NorthWind database, I wanted to get back the distinct regions from the territories...  This syntax worked correctly.

```
(from t in Territories
from r in Regions
select  new
{
    r.RegionDescription
})
.Distinct().OrderBy(r => r.RegionDescription)
```

There is a post on a Microsoft forum [here](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=420037) that may help.